# Java 9 module issue with unit tests in IntelliJ: Cannot require JUnit Jupiter

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, java-9

I am finally upgrading all of my projects from Java 8 to Java 14 and it's a giant PITA. Today's issue:

## Setup

- Java: 14
- Programming language: Kotlin 1.4.10 (shouldn't matter though IMO)
- Build system: Maven 3.6.3; maven-surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M5
- Test framework: JUnit Jupiter 5.7.0

## Dependency setup

Compile dependencies: None

Test dependencies:

- junit-jupiter-api
- junit-jupiter-engine
- junit-jupiter-params
- awaitility 4.0.3

## My issue

My maven build runs just fine and luckily all tests pass. However, IntelliJ shows me a lot of errors which all look like this:

```
Symbol is declared in module 'org.junit.jupiter.api' which current module does not depend on
```

The usual solution would be to add `requires org.junit.jupiter.api;` to my `module-info.java` but since my `module-info.java` is in my production code folder and not in my test folder and JUnit is only available in test scope, that won't work.

Again, I can run all tests in Maven and in IntelliJ, it's just that these errors are pretty annoying.

Comment: Is it somehow related to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321472/intellij-displays-error-message-when-unit-test-is-written-in-kotlin

Comment: Yes, that question seems to have slipped through my search efforts. Thanks :)
Edit: I voted to mark this question as a duplicate of the one you linked.